# c++(и другие ооп) компилятор не видит инициализации

Tags: инициализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор не читает инициализацию и выдает,что переменная tempVector не найдена.

Суть кода: Вектор инициализируется один раз,потом проталкивает в него несколько temp ,затем все повторяется.

Как реализовать создание вектора,чтобы он видел его во втором(наружном) if ?

Comment: А почему tempVector нельзя обьявить до `if` ? (это часный случай общей проблемы)

Comment: тут лучше http://mycpp.ru/cpp/book/c08.html

Comment: Внутренний if контролирует,чтобы вектор создавался один раз,если я его создам не в if ,то это будет не то,что мне нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В с++ есть правило, что все локальные переменные должны быть внутри зоны её видимости (кроме глобальных). Зона видимости - ограничена `{` `}`. Правило - нельзя использовать локальные переменные (а так же переменные класса и т д) за их зоной действия.

Поэтому... для вас есть несколько вариантов решения.

Вариант - статика, при этом варианте - переменная будет существовать до конца работы программы.

```
 static vector<string>  tempVector;
 if (ch = ';') {
     cTemp++;
     if (nextRow == true) {
        tempVector.clear();
        nextRow == false;
        }
     // ...
     }
```

Вариант - единая локальная

```
void your_function(){
 vector<string>  tempVector;
 //...

 if (ch = ';') {
     cTemp++;
     if (nextRow == true) {
        tempVector.clear();
        nextRow == false;
        }
     // ...
     }
  // ...
 }
```

Вариант - проброс через зону видимости, при повторном входе в зону видимости - будет создана новая переменная. cTemp - вниз, что б не затронуло повторное выполнение кода. Нужно понимать что код с `tempVector` по данный `break` будет выполнен повторно. Думаю вариант с clear Лучше.

```
void your_function(){
 bool not_ready = true;
 bool rescan = false;
 while (not_ready) {
    vector<string>  tempVector;
    //...
   if (ch = ';') {           
       if (nextRow == true){         
          break; // тут нужно что б случился выход на while             
        }
     cTemp++; 
     rescan = false;
     // ...
     // Добавить выход из цикла
     }
  // ...
 }
```

Остались более простые варианты, думаю они вам неподойдут, но в общем случае могут понадобится.

- Глобальная переменная.
- Переменная класса

Полезные ссылки

- Зона видимости http://mycpp.ru/cpp/book/c08.html

Comment: Мне понравился вариант единой локальной,спасибо.